# Jarallax local video integration in wordpress

Tags: parallax

I'm trying to implement the jarallax video JS for the background video parallax effect. But looks like the jarallax uses the absolute video path.

Instead I want to use the Video URL as below

Can anyone suggest me how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You have not included the type of video URL you want to use

Comment: I want to use the video url path

<div class="demo-carousel-item jarallax" data-jarallax='{"speed": 0.4}' style="background-image: url('video/local-video.jpg');" data-jarallax-video="mp4:video/http://localhost/video/local-video.mp4,webm:video/http://localhost/video/local-video.webm,ogv:video/http://localhost/video/local-video.ogv"></div>

Comment: Oops!

My mistake

I should have used the URLs in the video as follows

<div class="demo-carousel-item jarallax" data-jarallax='{"speed": 0.4}' style="background-image: url('video/local-video.jpg');" data-jarallax-video="mp4:http://localhost/video/local-video.m‌​p4,webm:http:/‌​/localhost/…

Now it's working but I've problem with the firefox browser the html5 video player are not loading but It's loading fine in chorme and opera. Can any one knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this like so in WordPress by uploading my video into the Media Library:

```
<div class="jarallax movie" data-jarallax-video="mp4:./wp-content/uploads/2017/10/example.mp4">

   <!-- any content you want overlaying the video here --> 


</div>
```

Don't forget that you need to include the script that's specific to video if you want to use video content:

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/jarallax@1.9/dist/jarallax-video.min.js"></script>`

Also remember to call Jarallax via jQuery, JS, or whatever method of your choosing to init it.